# Click on a element with same class that matches text and exit in Protractor

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium, protractor, end-to-end

I am able to find the text by using `element.all(by.repeater())` in protractor and using each to check for matching text. Now the problem is exiting once the match is done and clicking on the matched element.

I tried using `.each()`, but unable to exit iteration.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `each()` is not a good choice. *It really sounds like [filtering](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter)*, example:

```
element.all(by.repeater("test in tests")).filter(function (elm) {
    return elm.getText().then(function (text) {
        return text === "Desired text";
    });
}).then(function(filteredElements) {
    filteredElements[0].click();
});
```

Comment: Its working good in chrome, but when i use the same in safari its not working? Is there a way to do the same, its able to retrieve the filteredElements, but filteredElements[0].click(); is not able to click in safari

Comment: @SPatchamatla I remember multiple problems when using safari driver. Please define "not working". Thanks.

Comment: I'm able to make it work now, in chrome even though the parent tag which doesn't have a ng-click, chrome is able to click on the element. But In safari, i need to make sure its pointing to the child node which has ng-click and then only safari is able to click on the webElement.